# How do I combine two lists?

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8

I have two lists- cuisine list(cuid, name) and location list(locid, locname). I want to combine these two list into one. how to do this?

Comment: A list of what? list where ids are the same? names are the same? new object with all elements? what have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand of your message is that you would like to display 2 types of objects into a `ListBox` (or `LongListSelector`). Is is right ?

If it is, you should read [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/06/multiple-item-templates-in-windows-phone.aspx). It explains how to put multiple item templates in a list